# Is it possible to get information about the operator on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, gsm

Is it possible to get information about the GSM operator from an iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use the [Core Telephony framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) to retrieve this information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for that. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853467/retreiving-carrier-name-from-iphone-programmatically/853982#853982) on similar question points to private API, but you can't use it if you want to get to AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember seeing something on that topic.

http://www.handsetdetection.com/

Check out that site and see if they have an answer.