# Getting Carrier name in Cocoa Touch app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to get the name of the current carrier of the phone inside a Cocoa Touch application?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853467/retreiving-carrier-name-from-iphone-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

You can from iOS4+

First add the CoreTelephony.framework to your project.

Then import the following to the top of your .h or .m file:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
```

Use sample:

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netinfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSLog(@"Carrier name:%@", [carrier carrierName]);
```

Comment: From the Apple documentation `carrierName` is "The name of the user’s home cellular service provider." not the current carrier.  The home name (i.e. the one your account is charged to) does not change even when you are abroad and using a third party provider as your current service.

Answer (score -1):

The answers is No. Not officially. Not without Jailbreaking.