# How to get carrier name programmatically for iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retreiving Carrier Name from iPhone Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853467/retreiving-carrier-name-from-iphone-programmatically)

I am working on an application in which i need to find out Carrier Name while i am using CoreTelephony frameework i am getting error when i am trying to load it on device.  so is there any way to find out carrier name without using CoreTelephony framework?

Please give me quick response with code if you have??

Thank You in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

if the ios version is 4.0 or later. it will work definitely. please, check whether you are using the active sim or it should not be in flight mode.