# Get Access to CoreTelephony.framework

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I'm using [nst's iOS Runtime Headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers) to get access to the CoreTelephony.framework.

Here is his sample code:

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework"];
BOOL success = [b load];

Class FTDeviceSupport = NSClassFromString(@"FTDeviceSupport");
id si = [FTDeviceSupport valueForKey:@"sharedInstance"];

NSLog(@"-- %@", [si valueForKey:@"deviceColor"]);
```

His sample usage code gives me access to FTServices.framework but when I apply the same logic, it fails since CoreTelephony does not house a class method named sharedInstance().

Should I declare and implement that myself or is there another way?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

My attempt:

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework"];
BOOL success = [b load];

Class CTTelephonyNetworkInfo = NSClassFromString(@"CTTelephonyNetworkInfo");
id si = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo valueForKey:@"sharedInstance"]; // fails here

NSLog(@"-- %@", [si valueForKey:@"cachedSignalStrength"]);
```

Comment: Can you please post your own code attempt? Which class in CoreTelephony are you trying to access?

Comment: @Flying_Banana Please see the edit.

Comment: Why are you trying to access it like that? CoreTelephony is a public framework.

Comment: @dan I'm aware of it but I need access to things private in that public framework for research purposes. Am I on the wrong path?

Comment: Yes, you can just create a `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` object normally and then access the private property you want using `valueForKey:` like the last line in your snippet.

Comment: @dan Yeah that worked. Thanks. But how can I access instance methods as well. They're not defined in the public headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` *actually* has no property `sharedInstance`. Referred from [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h), `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` is a data structure designed to house the relevant info, and can be accessed (constructed) directly through the standard `[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init]` (referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204121/getting-operator-details-in-iphone)).

So for your case:

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework"];
BOOL success = [b load];

Class CTTelephonyNetworkInfo = NSClassFromString(@"CTTelephonyNetworkInfo");
id si = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];

NSLog(@"-- %@", [si valueForKey:@"cachedSignalStrength"]);
```

Make sure you test on an actual phone though! Simulators have no such information stored.

Edits:
If you want to call methods on a generated class, use [`performSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:) or [`NSInvocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocation) class.

Comment: The sample usage works for me as well. It's just that I can't modify it to work with CoreTelephony.

Comment: Edited. Sorry about the initial answer, thought it was your own attempt! :)

Comment: Could you also share a snippet as well please?

Comment: Tried your snippet on an actual device but returned null. Also how can I call methods?

Comment: Apparently that `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` only gives you access to the carrier's information, as referred from [Apple's description](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo). I've updated the answer for calling methods.

Comment: Maybe it's that CoreTelephony requires entitlement in order to work. Anyways, much appreciated!