# iOS I can't get my carrier name

Tags: ios, core-telephony, carrier

as explained here -> [Retrieving Carrier Name from iPhone Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853467/retreiving-carrier-name-from-iphone-programmatically)

i'm trying to get my carrier's name, i'm using this code

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netinfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSLog(@"Carrier Name: %@", [carrier carrierName]);
[netinfo release];
```

but i receive a warning on `[carrier carrierName]`: Instance method '-carrierName' not found

i've added  and the framework coretelephony to my project but when i execute my app it crashes!

thanks to all!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you explicitly import CTCarrier?

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
```

Comment: I was importing only <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>... -.-' thank you!

Comment: im getting carrier as CTCarrier (0x174059200) {
 Carrier name: [Carrier]

Comment: Please ask a new question.  This one had to do with a build failure.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem too,and try to log by device:

```
NSLog(@"carrierName = %@",carrier.carrierName);
NSLog(@"mobileCountryCode = %@",carrier.mobileCountryCode);
NSLog(@"mobileNetworkCode = %@",carrier.mobileNetworkCode);
NSLog(@"isoCountryCode = %@",carrier.isoCountryCode);
NSLog(@"allowVOIP = %d",carrier.allowsVOIP);
```

result:

2012-05-29 11:48:31.466 carrierTest[357:707] mobileCountryCode = 466

2012-05-29 11:48:31.469 carrierTest[357:707] mobileNetworkCode = 97

2012-05-29 11:48:31.470 carrierTest[357:707] isoCountryCode = tw

2012-05-29 11:48:31.472 carrierTest[357:707] allowVOIP = 1

the object carrierName is "....." in run stack,actually it should be "台湾大哥大"

it seem like string encoding problem cause i can't get it?   I have no idea...

you can try the other carrier SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSLog(@"Carrier Name: %@", carrier.carrierName);
```

instead.

Comment: it says "Poperty 'carrierName' cannot be found in forward class object 'CTCarrier *'

Comment: which iOS are you compiling for, by the way? 3.0 or 4.0 or?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 like this

> 0000000100000001 for first sim

> 0000000100000002 for secound sim if mobile has 2 sim cards

```
import CoreTelephony

let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()

var cc: String = ""
var mnc: String = ""
var mcc: String = ""
var cn: String = ""

if let providers = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders, let carrier = providers["0000000100000001"]{
            cc  = carrier.isoCountryCode ?? ""
            mnc = carrier.mobileNetworkCode ?? ""
            mcc = carrier.mobileCountryCode ?? ""
            cn =  carrier.carrierName ?? ""
 }
```