# Get Mobile Carrier Info Phonegap

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to get the mobile service carrier from a phonegap app? I would like to know which carrier my users belong to.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get this information without a plugin. Take a look at questions about natively getting carrier info, then use that to build your own plugin (if you can't find one). You could use questions like [this one for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138662/ios-i-cant-get-my-carrier-name) and [this one for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838602/how-to-find-out-carriers-name-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but only through a plugin since it needs to access native code in order to do so.

I just made a phonegap/cordova plugin for that. It works both on iOS and Android: https://github.com/dtmtec/cordova-plugin-carrier/