# iOS Objective-C read cellular network provider

Tags: ios

On iPhone we have Carrier name displayed next to the cellular connection signal strength in a left corner. There are some apps that can modify this name. Is there a way to read this value via APIs? It differs from CTCarrier.carrierName when roaming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retreiving Carrier Name from iPhone Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853467/retreiving-carrier-name-from-iphone-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

I really dont understand your question, if you want to get the Carrier Name this is the code:

```
Prefix: #import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
        #import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>


CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [info subscriberCellularProvider];

NSString *string = [carrier carrierName];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. CTCarrier.carrierName displays info for the carrier of sim card, not the name of the carrier on which user is roaming. I'd like to know if it is possible to get roaming carrierName.