# Roaming Status in iPhone

Tags: objective-c

```
static NSString *carrierPListSymLinkPath = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.carrier.plist";

static NSString *operatorPListSymLinkPath = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.operator.plist";

- (BOOL)isRoaming
{

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *error;

    NSString *carrierPListPath = [fm destinationOfSymbolicLinkAtPath:carrierPListSymLinkPath error:&error];
    NSString *operatorPListPath = [fm destinationOfSymbolicLinkAtPath:operatorPListSymLinkPath error:&error];
    return ([operatorPListPath isEqualToString:carrierPListPath]);

}
```

Here I am trying to read carrier.plist and operator.plist. It working fine.

Now my question is Apple will accept this code or not for app store release, I don't know.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your device jailbroken? And what is the Use Case for knowing the roaming status?  because Apple takes user privacy seriously.

Comment: Also, your should read the answers and comments to this question: [Retreiving Carrier Name from iPhone Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853467/retreiving-carrier-name-from-iphone-programmatically)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asking if my app with get rejected by Apple App Store.

Comment: No my device is not jailbroken.If I will know the roaming status I will decide whether to download from server or not in order to avoid high cost in roaming.

Comment: Apple will not reject it...I have several Apps with this code inside in Apple store...